# Read first line of splitlines() file

Tags: python

I am having trouble converting this code snippet into reading only the first line of the file, rather than opening it random.

Can somebody help?

```html
lines = open('myfile.txt').read().splitlines()
account =random.choice(lines)
```

Comment: what? that's probably covered in the first lecture of any course. show some effort of learning on your side.

Comment: If you only want the first line of the file, why read the whole file to memory?

Comment: @YotamSalmon because I am just starting to learn python and didn't know better.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr thanks for being so kind. You were born as perfect coder? Never had to learn python?

Comment: Ok. However you should use something like @chepner's answer. It seems like the clearest option out there.

Comment: sorry to be mad; however, it's non-economical if you try to ask every single question of this kind without actually acquiring the skills of learning from resources like search engines or books.

Comment: @YotamSalmon In this case it doesn't really matter, because the file will never contain more than 10 lines of short usernames. It is perfectly okay to read them all into the memory. For longer lists, I'll keep the other solutions in mind! Thank you!

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Please check my other questions. I already tried a lot. This time I was just overstrained by all the solutions from open to with open, closing files and not needed to. Then to read them line by line, only the first line. It was simply too much. But I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 4):

If you only want the first line, then only read the first line.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
```

Above, `f.readline()` reads until a newline or EOF.

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the fact that the file object itself is iterable:

```
>>> with open('multiline.txt') as file:
...     line1 = next(file)

>>> line1
'this is line 1\n'
```

This doesn't waste memory by reading the entire file into a list.

However, I'd say @chepner's answer would be the "prescribed" way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your code, you can simply change the second line to

```
first_line = lines[0]
```

and you are done.

Comment: I don't know why this post has been voted down - it fits the best to my code and works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Because your question wasn’t “how do I access the first element of a list?” It was “how can I *read* only the first line of a file.” @daniel_e

Comment: @BradSolomon okay, then sorry for the inconvenience!